# Extracting value from request body in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to extract a dynamic value from Jmeter Request body, i am using regular expression extract and storing inside a variable but when I am using that variable somewhere, extracted value is not coming
Can someone help me with this?

I am trying to extract value from request body using regular expression extractor but it's not working i have tried almost everything as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot use Regular Expression Extractor for extracting values from request **body**, the only request field you can work with is [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
2. In general I fail to see why do you need to extract the values from **request** body because it's **you** who sends the request so you should know everything about it, there is no need to extract anything from there.

If it's some form of an academic interest you can access request body and extract the required parts of it (or body fully) using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) (or PostProcessor) via `sampler` shorthand like:

```
vars.put('requestBody', sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
```

where:

- `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance
- `sampler` returns an instance of the current Sampler in the PreProcessor's scope, for [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) it will be [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html). See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) for more information on the above and other JMeter API shorthands

and then use Regular Expression extractor on the `requestBody` variable.